# ostrio:logger no client logs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

i have initialized the logger like in the docs: https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/logger
with a transport to mongodb: https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/loggermongo#initialization-isomorphic

```
import { Logger } from 'meteor/ostrio:logger';
import { LoggerMongo } from 'meteor/ostrio:loggermongo';

export const idLogger = new IdLogger();

export function addMongoDbLogging(idLogger, filters) {
  (new LoggerMongo(idLogger , {
    collection: AppLogs,
  })).enable({
    enable: true,
    filter: filters,
    client: true,
    server: true,
  });
}
```

The code lies is in the imports directory
And the call to is in the server directory during meteor startup.

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
  initLogger(); // calls addMongoDbLogging();
}
```

On The server logging works with no problems. All logs are written in the AppLogs Collection.
But when i try to log something from the client... nothing happens.

Same behavior is for other transports like console. See: https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/loggerconsole

Serverside all logs show up in my console. Client logs are not shown on neither server or client consoles.

Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Update: It could be that the `server/startup` is not the right place for isomorphic code. Where should this be put?

Comment: Where and when do you subscribe to the AppLogs collection on the client, and do you use `allow` to permit insertion from the client?

Comment: I haven't done a publication of AppLogs and don't use allow etc.. It's a good comment and i can add this. But it wouldn't explain, why also the console logging (it's basically another transport same as the mongo logging) does not work. See edits.

Comment: Edit. Ignore my previous comment. I forgot that I already have a publication for AppLogs, since i show logs on client side.

Comment: @ChristianFritz it could be something, where the initialization is. Maybe the server/startup is not the way to go for isomorphic code.

Answer (score -1):

Ok i found the problem.

It was the location of the code.

It has to be done in the `/lib` folder.